# decreasing values with loop in Django

Tags: python, django, loops

in this code, I tried to decrease the quantity of products from the database when the user places the order, it is working but the problem is just decreasing from the first product in the cart?

```
  new_order_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        for item in new_order_items:
            OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=neworder,
                product=item.product,
                price=item.product.selling_price,
                quantity=item.product_quantity
            )
            # decrease the product quantity from table
            order_product = Product.objects.filter(id=item.product_id).first()
            order_product.quantity = order_product.quantity - item.product_quantity
            order_product.save()
```

Comment: Can you print `order_product.quantity` and `item.product_quantity`? Hope it will give you an idea of what you are getting from DB.

Answer (score 0):

i'm suggesting to not use a loop for the filtered item that will cause a performance issue, instead
you could use [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)
and instead of looping for each item you can use `.values()` method

```
products_id=Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('product_id')
#that will return a query set of item ids
```

then you can search by query using `field__in=` for example :

```
order_product = Product.objects.filter(id__in=item.products_id)
#that will return a query set of products with that id
```

Comment: Thanks,  can you convert my code above to use bulk_create(), I will appreciate it

Comment: `OrderItem.objects.bulk_create([OrderItem(#pass parameters) for item in new_order_items ])` where Comprehension are much faster than normal loop